# HTML Horizontal Scrolling On Overflow Text On Code Element

Tags: html, word-wrap

I'm looking to have a scroll effect (left to right) on text placed inside code tags within a pre tag. I've tried the `overflow: scroll` attribute without success. An example is this:

```
<pre><code>
    var text = 'This is a bit of longer text that ends up wrapping around and messing up the rest of the formatting.';
    var object {
        text: text,
        key: 'A second key with some more really long text that will overflow onto the next line',
    }
</code></pre>
```

What style do I need to give to my code element to allow the text to wrap without effecting the formatting of the code? Ironically code in stack overflow has the effect I'm looking for though I can't seem to replicate it.

*I've updated the question to add that the code is in a pre tag which preserves line breaks and formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple and good example on how to do it !

**HTML**

```
<div class="code-holder">
  <code>
    ar text = 'This is a bit of longer text that ends up wrapping around and 
     messing up the rest of the formatting.';
  </code>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.code-holder{
  width: 560px; /* your prefered width */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 60px;/* Your prfered height*/
}

.code-holder code{
 white-space: nowrap; /* this rule is important*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks this does what I'm looking for. One question though, if I have the <code> tags wrapped in <pre> tags it seems like I lose the wrapping effect. What can I do to preserve the effect inside of a <pre> tag?

Comment: @JonLamb  please vote up and accept the question :)  for the <pre> tag do the same give it the same property `white-space: nowrap` thanks !!

Comment: When I add the `white-space: nowrap ` property to the <pre> tag I end up losing all the formatting of the text inside those tags, it all gets condensed into one line. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I've got this working now but I had to use `white-space: pre` on the code tag instead. The final css looks like: `.code-holder{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.code-holder code{
    white-space: pre;
}`